# How to create block with curved sides as in the picture?

Tags: html, css

How to create block with curved sides as in the picture?
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCyWw.png

I  [created](http://jsfiddle.net/Nac5V)
 a block with shadows of both sides.  But how create the effect of curved sides I don't know.

```
.comment{
  height:260px;
  width:280px;      
  margin: 10px auto;      
  padding: 0 40px;
  box-shadow:  -23px 0px 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
  23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);   
 }
```

Comment: i think it is magic of box-shadow + border-radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add border-radius

```
.comment{
  height:260px;
  width:280px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  box-shadow:
   -23px 0px 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
   23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 5% /50%;
}
```

An example here :

http://jsfiddle.net/Nac5V/7/

Comment: Thank you, srekoble, you very helped me!)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this: [**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vedant_Terkar/Nac5V/8/)

you'll have to add `border-radius` to `bottom-left` and `bottom-right` corners

and will have to remove from `top-left` and `top-right` corner as :

```
.comment{
height:260px;
width:280px;
margin: 10px auto;
padding: 40px;
margin-bottom:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
box-shadow:
   -23px 0px 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
   23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
border-radius:15%/70%;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
}
```

also do have a look at `margin-bottom` and `padding-bottom`.

hope it'll help you.. cheers !

Comment: Thank you, Vedant Terkar, you very helped me)